# How to use Bootstap mb- mt- in resolution dependent, responsive way?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**Context**

I have a `<div class="mt-5 mb-5">`. In desktop resolution I see in Chrome dev tools the margins are  72px, and the style in effect is coming from Bootstrap: `margin-bottom: 4.5rem!important;` This looks fine visually.

If I switch to mobile device dimensions in Chrome dev tools, say iPhone 6, and refresh the page, the div's margin are still 72px, what is way to big in this resolutiom.

**Question**

I would like to way smaller margins in this resolution, while keeping the 72px in desktop resolution. How can I achieve this, preferably in bootstrap supported way?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the breakpoints in combination with these utility classes.

`class="mt-lg-1 mt-md-4"` works, it sets the margin-top for lg to 1 and for md devices to 4

[Check the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#notation) for more info on that

`The classes are named using the format {property}{sides}-{size} for xs and {property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size} for sm, md, lg, and xl.`